# Dygraph javascript to PNG incorrect zoom

Tags: javascript, png, zooming, dygraphs

I have a question regarding dygraphs in javascript. I have created a graph and want to export it to a PNG image:

```
function drawChart() {
            g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("dg_div"),
```

```
function export_graph() {
            let img = document.getElementById('dg_img')
            Dygraph.Export.asPNG(g, img)
```

This produces the following graph:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVnJZ.png)
And the following PNG image:
[PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFGcA.png)

The PNG is incorrectly zoomed in to the graphs top left corner, tho the axes remain the correct size.

I have tried things like .resetZoom() or checking if the user options have any effect. They do not. It seems to be a problem in the dygraph-extra library. Any solutions would be a big help!

Answer (score 0):

The dygraph-extra library needs a little change:

```
Dygraph.Export.drawPlot = function (canvas, dygraph, options)
```

This function needs to change this line:

```
ctx.drawImage(plotCanvas, 0, 0);
```

Into this:

```
ctx.drawImage(plotCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```